# How to login with facebook or link facebook account to current user in user pool

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, federated-identity, aws-userpools

I am using cognito & node serverless framework in my app to manage users. I have been able to perform operations on cognito (Signup, Login etc) using amazon-cognito-identity-js. However I need to implement two features.

1. Login with facebook
2. Link facebook account with current loggedin user.

I have searched and read alot of articles but couldn't make any sense on how to achieve this.

So far I have been able to get identityId from AWS library using the following gist. https://gist.github.com/brianberlin/443c3bd005ff63282394
However I am not sure what to do about the identityId I am getting from AWS.

I am not even sure that I am on right direction or not so any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Hint: [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org).

Comment: @tadman I'm using serverless so passport can't be used.